# Iptables Syntax Substitute Network Interface Name for Eth1

Tags: networking, iptables

Working through a book on firewalls and thus iptables. 
I'm wondering whether eth1 can or should be replaced with the name of the 
physical network device as it's listed per the operating system.
i.e.

```bsh
  $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth1 -s $INT_NET --dport 21 --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

versus

```bsh
 $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -i 240sx -s $INT_NET --dport 21 --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Let's say eth1, or even eth0 is replaced with 240sx, as that's the actual name of the network device as recognized by the operating system. Can I then replace eth1 or eth0 with 240sx within all context within the iptables script?

Comment: If that's what `ip a s` shows it as, that should work. (My understanding of current naming conventions, at least for Linux, is that ethernet adapters would have names starting with `e`, though, so I'm a bit confused by `240sx`.)

Comment: it's not an actual ethernet port, was just using it as an example of it being arbitrary. enp0s25 is what actually needs to be used here.